# Changing the company logo of the website dosen't change it (Suite CRM)

Tags: php, suitecrm

I am new in Suite CRM platform. I have uploaded the company logo from the option provided. i.e. Admin --> System Settings --> Upload logo.

**Version 7.10.11 

Sugar Version 6.5.25 (Build 344)**

It dosent reflect in the website.

[image]

[image]

I have tried several links, but was unsuccessful. Please guide how can it be done:

https://suitecrm.com/suitecrm/forum/suitecrm-7-0-discussion/7562-own-logo-in-suitecrm

https://suitecrm.com/suitecrm/forum/suitecrm-7-0-discussion/7562-own-logo-in-suitecrm#27038

https://suitecrm.com/suitecrm/forum/developer-help/7931-new-logo-not-allowed

Answer (score 0):

That is usually caused by wrong permissions in the file system.

If you are hosting on linux you can do

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \; &&  find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \; 
chmod -R 775 cache custom modules themes data upload  config_override.php  config.php
chown -R www-data:www-data .
```

Make sure to adjust the user in the last command, if you are using ubuntu www-data will work fine.